# Using Jquery moble with old fashioned hrefs just wont work right

Tags: jquery-mobile

Have been bashing my head against the wall for a good day and a half now.  Did everyone abandon old fashioned page structures to go to jQuery Mobile?

I have a webpage, tracks legislation.  Main navbar goes as such:
`/bills/list`, `/legislators/list`, `/committees/list`

Where each link is rewritten into

```
index.php?category=$1&detail=$2
```

so `/bills/list` translates to

```
index.php?category=bills&detail=list
```

But when I load a page from the navbar, using an `a href` tag, the pages load all nice and easy using the AJAX loader, but the newly loaded pages 1. don't run scripts, and 2. don't display any formatting.  This is a problem.

All the suggestions I have seen say to `.bind` something or `.refresh` or `.trigger`  without any context of where that goes, and everything I have tried in that vein has frustrated me to no end.

Please help!  And by the way, if I just `data-ajax=false` everything it works perfectly.  But I want the quick loading that ajax gives! I just don't understand how it works and there are really no good pointers on the web  I could find.

Code in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/9jMxV0B6
You can see some artifacts of my struggling to get the thing working.

From what I gather, you shouldn't call new pages via `a href`, but then why the hell does jqm use href's for its nav menu? Is that supposed to call a function or something?

Comment: so you just replace the whole page or just navbar? the code you gave is incorrectly formated. e.g. ln31 has extra tags and many other place also. Please clean your code first.

Comment: you have `data-ajax` false, pages will loaded without ajax, meaning, if that HTML file has no JS libraries placed in `head`, it wont look styled. Where did you read that new pages shouldn't be loaded via `href`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"But when I load a page from the navbar, using a basic old fashioned a href tag, the pages load all nice and easy using the AJAX loader, but the newly loaded pages 1. don't run scripts, and 2. don't display any formatting. This is a problem."

That happens because JQM ignores all the headers in all other pages besides the first page that loads. So  if you want to do any changes to the page use page events, place them In first page.

I had problems understanding it also. Here is a link to my previous post  that explains it a bit: [How do I enable onload in jQuery mobile (open page both from link & load)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245574/how-do-i-enable-onload-in-jquery-mobile-open-page-both-from-link-load)

Hope it clears some things for you. My recommendation for you is to do two simple pages and test simple URL functionality.

Comment: Thanks, starting to get this.  I get it's a different way to go about it. Appreciate your help.  Would upvote but not enough reputation.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_page.asp is a good link also. It has simple examples. You can mark my response as an answer if you like to. Happy to help!